# How to use a config map to create a single file within container?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, openshift

I'm trying to configure Nginx container on Openshift. My final goal is to overwrite Nginx config file. I know it's possible using config maps. Because any failure with modifying Nginx config directories is crashing the container, temporarily my goal is to just create an index.html file in /opt/app-root/src directory.

I'm facing two problems depends on the configuration

- config map overwrite whole /opt/app-root/src directory
- config map creates index.html directory with index file inside

Config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  index: |-
    <html>
    <body>
    yo yo!
    </body>
    </html>
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2020-01-16T12:53:25Z'
  name: index-for-nginx
  namespace: some-namespace
```

Deployment config (part, related to the topic):

```
spec:
  containers:
    - image: someimage
      ...
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/app-root/src/index.html
          name: index
  volumes:
    - configMap:
        defaultMode: 420
        name: index-for-nginx
      name: index
```

When:

```
volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/app-root/src/index.html
```

It creates index.html directory and index file (with proper content) in /opt/app-root/src

When:

```
volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/app-root/src/
```

It overwrites /opt/app-root/src directory

My question is - how should I configure it to create index.html file in /opt/app-root/src without overwriting the directory?

Comment: Use `subpath: index.html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `subPath` to mount the single file you want.

```
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /opt/app-root/src/index.html
    subPath: index
    name: index
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, taken from this GitHub issue

```
containers:
- volumeMounts:
  - name: config-volumes
    mountPath: /opt/app-root/src/index.html
    subPath: index
volumes:
- name: config-volumes
  configMap:
    name: index-for-nginx
```

**Note: A container using a ConfigMap as a subPath volume will not receive ConfigMap updates.**